# What's the difference between getHits() and getGetOperationCount() in the local map statistics?

Tags: hazelcast

We want to analyze the performance of our Hazelcast caches. It's a distributed map on a cluster with six members and a backup count of 5.

We don't understand what getGetOperationCount() returns in difference to getHits(). In one case we have 69.932.537 cache hits but only 1.354 get operations, which makes no sense to us.

Can someone explain the meaning of this? Thank you!

Comment: I think `getGetOperationCount()` returns the number of `get()` calls (any read attempts) whereas `getHits()` returns the number of `get()` calls that actually read an entry (were successful). Javadocs are [here](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/monitor/LocalMapStats.html#getGetOperationCount--)

Comment: In this case the number of get operations should be equal or higher than the number of cache hits. But in our case it's much, much lower.

Comment: If you read the docs, it states that the numbers may be inconsistent (in case of master node changes). But I could be wrong anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Hits increase with both read and write operations while `getGetOperationCount()` only with `IMap.get()` operations.

Answer (score 0):

getHits() is looking at the local member (cluster node), while the various operation counts (getGetOperationCount(), getPutOperationCount(), etc.) are for the cluster as a whole.   That doesn't really explain the difference you're seeing; I'd expect the local hit count to be about one sixth of the total operation count.   (Using getEventOperationCount() rather than getGetOperationCount() might give a better comparison).

The values are longs so a counter overflow doesn't seem likely, unless you're fetching the counters and storing them as ints somewhere along the way.

Edited to add: With 5 backups, if you have read-backup-data set true then you should always hit locally.